# Minimize a Weighted Error Function

Tags: statistics, error-function

**Problem:**
Given $((x_{11},...,x_{1M},y_1),...,(x_{N1},...,x_{NM},y_N))$ and the weights $w_1,...,w_N$ , where for every $n$ is true that $w_n>0$ . Find the $θ_0,θ_1,...,θ_M$ which minize the following error function:

$$J(θ_0,θ_1,...,θ_M)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n\left(y_n-θ_0-\sum_{m=1}^{M}θ_mx_{nm}\right)^2$$

Comment: Solve the system of $M+1$ linear equations of the form $\frac{\text{d}J}{\text{d}\theta_i}=0,~i=0,\dots,M$ and you get the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the analytical solution as an answer would be perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us evaluate $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}J}{\text{d}\theta_i},~i=0,\dots,M$ to make expressions easier:
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}J}{\text{d}\theta_0}&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n\left(y_n-θ_0-\sum_{m=1}^{M}θ_mx_{nm}\right)=0,\\
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}J}{\text{d}\theta_i}&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n\left(y_n-θ_0-\sum_{m=1}^{M}θ_mx_{nm}\right)x_{ni}=0,~i=1,\dots,M.
\end{align}
After rearranging the above equations we get the linear system
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n\theta_0+\sum_{j=1}^M\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_nx_{nj}\right]\theta_j&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n y_n \\
\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n\theta_0+\sum_{j=1}^M\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_nx_{nj}x_{ni}\right]\theta_j&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n y_n x_{ni},~i=1,\dots,M. \\
\end{align}
The system can be written as follows:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n & \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n x_{n1} & \dots &  \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n x_{nM}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n & \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n x_{n1}x_{n1} & \dots & \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n x_{n1}x_{nM} \\
           \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n &  \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n x_{nM}x_{n1} & \dots & \sum_{n=M}^{N}w_n x_{n1}x_{nM} \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\theta_0 \\ \theta_1 \\ \vdots \\ \theta_M           
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n y_n \\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n y_nx_{n1} \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{n=1}^{N}w_n y_nx_{nM}
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
which is a linear system of equations of the form $A\mathbf{\theta}=b$.

Let us further show that the least square functionals are convex. In general the functional can be written in the form $J(x)=\sum_i (A_ix-b_i)^2$. Let us show that $J(x)$ is convex. Let $x\neq y$. We show that for any convex combination $J\left(\theta x+(1-\theta)y\right)\le\theta J(x)+(1-\theta)J(y)$. And really:
\begin{align}
  &J\left(\theta x+(1-\theta)y\right)=\sum_i \left[\theta(A_ix-b_i)+(1-\theta)(A_iy-b_i)\right]^2=\nonumber\\
  &\sum_i\left[\theta^2(A_ix-b_i)^2+2\theta(1-\theta)(A_ix-b_i)(A_iy-b_i)+(1-\theta)^2(A_iy-b_i)^2\right]\equiv\nonumber\\
  &\sum_i\left[\theta(A_ix-b_i)^2+(1-\theta)(A_iy-b_i)^2\underbrace{-\theta(1-\theta)\left[A_i(x-y)\right]^2}_{\le0}\right]\le\nonumber\\
  &\sum_i\left[\theta(A_ix-b_i)^2+(1-\theta)(A_iy-b_i)^2\right]=\theta J(x)+(1-\theta)J(y).~\spadesuit \nonumber
 \end{align}

Comment: If not mistaken, in order for this solution to be complete, we also need a proof for convexity

Comment: Of course it is convex - least square problems are always convex. The proof has been added above.

Comment: I am in search for a solution with less computations, If I could somehow build an inequality and find the lower bound of J, maybe with matrix calculus.

Comment: This is a standard approach. It is not demanding: you make just one matrix inversion and you have the solution.

Comment: I thought it is clear to you that it is a linear system. I adapt my answer a bit to make it obvious.

Comment: Everything is above, you invert it and it is done.